# Como repetir um trecho de código determinadas vezes?

Tags: python

Como repetir um trecho de código na quantidade de vezes que o usuário informar?

Isso foi o que tentei:

```
#Só um exemplo

import random    

gerar= int(input("digite quantos números deseja gerar,o limite máximo é 20"))

   c=("+55119")

   while        
    print(c,(random.randrange(1,100000001)))
```

Comment: `for _ in range(gerar): print(c,(random.randrange(1,100000001)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você começou bem, utilizando um loop while. Faltou adicionar a condição para repetir o código somente a quantidade informada na variável `gerar`.

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso. A forma que vou mostrar é subtraindo 1 a cada repetição, e parar o laço até que chegue em zero. Por exemplo:

```
>>> quantidade_de_repeticoes = 3
>>> while quantidade_de_repeticoes > 0:
...   print("oi")
...   quantidade_de_repeticoes -= 1
... 
oi
oi
oi
```

No seu caso, ficaria parecido com:

```
import random    

gerar = int(input("digite quantos números deseja gerar,o limite máximo é 20"))

c=("+55119")

while gerar != 0:     
    print(c, (random.randrange(1,100000001)))
    gerar -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

O Python tem dois comandos de *loop* para repetição de *suites*: [`for`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) e [`while`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp).

---

##### LOOP FOR

Para o laço `for`, será necessário o uso da função [`range`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) (que recebe como parâmetro inicial a quantidade de vezes que irá repetir um *suite* de código):

```
repeticoes = 5
for contador in range(repeticoes):
    print(contador)
```

Este *suite* irá imprimir a saída abaixo no *console*:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

##### LOOP WHILE

Para o laço `while` será necessária a criação de uma variável que será incrementada a cada repetição do *suite*.

Enquanto a condição avaliada resultar em `True`, o *suite* será repetido:

```
contador = 0
repeticoes = 5

while contador < repeticoes:
    print(contador)
    contador += 1  # a cada repetição, soma 1 no valor da variável contador
```

Este *suite* irá imprimir a saída abaixo no *console*:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

##### UTILIZANDO SEU EXEMPLO

Com base no seu exemplo, seria possível as seguintes implementações:

###### WHILE

```
import random    

gerar = int(input('Digite quantos números deseja gerar (o limite máximo é 20): '))
c = ('+55119')
contador = 0

while contador < gerar:
    print(c, random.randrange(1, 100000001))
    contador += 1
```

###### FOR

```
import random    

gerar = int(input('Digite quantos números deseja gerar (o limite máximo é 20): '))
c = ('+55119')

for contador in range(gerar):
    print(c, random.randrange(1, 100000001))
```